# Salesforce visual workflow creating event

Tags: visual-workflow

Does anyone know how to create an event in visual workflow - i know how to create the record i am just having issues creating the date time piece as you can not create datetime fields in VWF.

At the moment i have a picklist of times and a date field, i want to try and concatenate these and add in the rest of the values as if i was using the apex data loader but having issues doing this

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a long-winded approach, but I created a number of formula fields to cater for each of the datetime components and concatenated them together in a string.

```
YearFormula = YEAR({!RequiredDate})
MonthFormula = MONTH(...)
```

For the time component, I used:

```
TEXT({!Time}) & ":00:00"
```

where Time is the picklist value, which I exposed as a number.

The final step is to pull it together in another formula:

```
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT({!YearFormula}) & "-" & TEXT({!MonthFormula}) & "-" & TEXT({!DayFormula}) &" " & TEXT({!Time}) & ":00:00")
```

On record creation, the value of the formula is written to the Datetime field.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do date/time fields as of Spring 14. Just create a new variable like normal and choose DateTime as the variable type.

You should be able to use an Assignment element to "add" the data together, which will essentially perform a concatenation. You may need to also define a constant with a default value of " " (a space) to be between your date and your time, also concatenated in.

Comment: yes, there is a DateTime variable, i am just not sure on how to concatenate a date and a time to go in there as it only accepts date fields.
at the moment i have a date field and a time field, i can get the date into the field, i just dont know how to manipulate the time

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect the answer to your question is very similar to one that was just posted and answered a day or so ago titled [Can we do custom datetime in visual flows?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33246/can-we-do-custom-datetime-in-visual-flows/33266#33266) The methods you need were outlined in that post.